# This if statement should not detect 0; only null or empty strings

Tags: javascript, null, if-statement

Using JavaScript, how do I NOT detect 0, but otherwise detect null or empty strings?

Comment: use `val === ""` to ensure that val is a string in that second test.

Comment: I don't know about you, but it's easier for me to logically follow this sentence: "How do I detect null or empty strings, but not 0". The only reason I mention this is because structuring code in the order you'd say it can sometimes make it easier to implement.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From your question title:

```
if( val === null || val == "" )
```

I can only see that you forgot a `=` when attempting to strict-equality-compare `val` with the empty string:

```
if( val === null || val === "" )
```

Testing with Firebug:

```
>>> 0 === null || 0 == ""
true

>>> 0 === null || 0 === ""
false
```

**EDIT:** see CMS's comment instead for the explanation.

Comment: Oh so an empty string is the same as 0 with ==?  Odd.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes; in fact, that's one of the biggest reasons to prefer `===` over `==`. Due to automatic conversion, `false == 0 == ""`, but `false !== 0 !== ""`.

Comment: Good, good +1. Would a better word for *translated* be *coerced*? (just thinking aloud) :)

Comment: @alex: Yes, it would. Thanks :)

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks for the refresher in this question. I had forgotten that "" was considered "falsey." +1

Comment: Actually, `0 == ""` doesn't *coerce* to `false == false`, at the end the compared values will be: `0 == 0`. That happens because if one of the operands of the Equals Operator is a Number value, the other will be also converted to Number, and an empty or whitespace only string, type-converts to `0`, e.g.: `+""` or `Number("")`. Another example: `0 == { valueOf:function () { return 0;} }` evaluates to `true`, because the object defines an own `valueOf` method, which is used internally by the `ToNumber` operation, and we know it doesn't *coerce* to `false`, because an object is **never** *falsy*.

Comment: @CMS: Ah, OK — looks like I got carried away then. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 67):

If you want to detect all falsey values except zero:

```
if (!foo && foo !== 0)
```

So this will detect `null`, empty strings, `false`, `undefined`, etc.

Comment: You're almost there, might as well clarify what you mean by 'etc'.

Comment: elegant answer!  Exactly what I needed!  thanks 

Comment: it will not validate '' empty

Answer (score 1):

```js
function isNullOrEmptyString(val) {
  return (val === null || val === '');
}

console.log({
"isNullOrEmptyString(0)": isNullOrEmptyString(0), 
"isNullOrEmptyString('')": isNullOrEmptyString(""), 
"isNullOrEmptyString(null)": isNullOrEmptyString(null),
"isNullOrEmptyString('something')": isNullOrEmptyString("something"),
});
```

Comment: The OP asked isNullOrEmptyString , that returns true for “” and null, but false for 0.

Answer (score -1):

I know this might be a too late answer but it might help someone else.

If I understand you correctly you want the below statement to exclude the 0:

```
 if(!value) {
    //Do things
 }
```

I think the easiest way to do this is to write the statement like this:

```
if(!value && value !== 0) {
  //Do things
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The OP wanted to exclude 0,  your (value === 0)  include 0

Comment: This statement does exclude 0 from checking "null, false, undefined etc.., it's exactly the same as this one 
"if (!value&& value!== 0) "
except that it's reversed.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, because it should be reversed. Also OP doesn’t ask about false etc

Comment: Yes, you're right, maybe I wrote it that way because this is the answer "I" would expect in a case like this because I usually check if there is a value then do things with this value not the other way around. @MichaelFreidgeim

Comment: Updated the answer to match the OP case